# Is it possible to send a tkinter widget as a parameter to function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Is it possible to send widgets as a parameter to any function? Such that:

```
l=Listbox(root,selectmode=MULTIPLE)

def SelectLB(lb):
    for i in range(lb["menu"].index("end")):
        l.select_set(i)

MyButton1=Button(root,text="MB1",command= lambda: SelectLB(l))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is yes, you can send anything anywhere in Python (disregarding pickling and multiprocessing). It seems though you are asking if you can call the button command function with a predefined argument. This is also possible:

```
MyButton1=Button(root, text="MB1", command=lambda l=l: SelectLB(l))
```

Here you are setting the default argument of`l` to the `l` in your current scope. This is a sort of closure, and will ensure `l` will be used every time the button is passed.

Comment: Thank you, a quick follow-up question, can I achieve this with tkinter.bind?

Comment: @mesboomin If you mean providing a `lambda` with a default for the callback argument then yes, this works anywhere a function is accepted (and so a lambda).

Comment: @mesboomin By the way, I noticed you used that new thank-you thing. Did you also upvote? there is a big discussion about this on meta.